# How do I go about adding an image into a java project with eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, image, resources

I've done a lot of reading around SO and Google links.

I have yet to figure out how to correctly add an image into an eclipse gui project is such a way that the system will recognize find it. I know there's some mumbojumbo about CLASSPATH but it probably shouldn't be this difficult to do.

Let me start by describing what I'm doing...(If someone could correct me, it'd be appreciated.)

Here is my method.

I add the image using the "import wizard" (right click, "import", "general", "file") into an "import directory" I called "/resources"

Eclipse automatically creates a folder called "resources" in the eclipse package explorer's tree view. Right under the entry for "Referenced Libraries".

Note, "resources" isn't under "Referenced Libraries", it's at the same level in the tree.

I then use the following code:

```
ClassLoader classLoader = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();
InputStream input = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("/resources/image.jpg");
Image logo = ImageIO.read(input);
```

And at this point, I run the test program and get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: input == null!
    at javax.imageio.ImageIO.read(Unknown Source)
    at Test.main(Test.java:17)
```

Thanks for any help in advance!

Answer (score 39, accepted):

Place the image in a *source folder*, not a regular folder.  That is: right-click on project -> New -> Source Folder.  Place the image in that source folder.  Then:

```
InputStream input = classLoader.getResourceAsStream("image.jpg");
```

Note that the path is omitted.  That's because the image is directly in the root of the path.  You can add folders under your source folder to break it down further if you like.  Or you can put the image under your existing source folder (usually called `src`).

Comment: agreed, OP the reason is, that eclipse automatically copies files from the src directories to the classes directory. It does not do this for ordinary directories, and why you get that error.

Comment: I see this posting is 2 years old, but for the people who reach through the search engines, I am adding that, if you run this code from within a static method, it will throw an error unless you change the definition of the input variable to:    InputStream input = LoadImg.class.getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("hockeypuck.jpg");

Comment: But, how you add the image to the folder in Eclipse?

Comment: @CodeMed [This answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/34433195) provides another way to hook in: `getClass().getResourceAsStream("image.jpg")`.

Comment: "Place the image in a source folder", that solved the problem, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

You can resave the image and literally find the src file of your project and add it to that when you save. For me I had to go to netbeans and found my project and when that comes up it had 3 files src was the last. Don't click on any of them just save your pic there. That should work. Now resizing it may be a different issue and one I'm working on now lol

Comment: This is not as good of an answer as the previous 2 answers. Please read the other answers before answering.

Answer (score 0):

If you still have problems with Eclipse finding your files, you might try the following:

1. Verify that the file exists according to the current execution environment by using the java.io.File class to get a canonical path format and verify that (a) the file exists and (b) what the canonical path is.
2. Verify the default working directory by printing the following in your main:

   ```
       System.out.println("Working dir:  " + System.getProperty("user.dir"));
   ```

For (1) above, I put the following debugging code around the specific file I was trying to access:

```
            File imageFile = new File(source);
            System.out.println("Canonical path of target image: " + imageFile.getCanonicalPath());
            if (!imageFile.exists()) {
                System.out.println("file " + imageFile + " does not exist");
            }
            image = ImageIO.read(imageFile);
```

For whatever reason, I ended up ignoring most of the other posts telling me to put the image files in "src" or some other variant, as I verified that the system was looking at the root of the Eclipse project directory hierarchy (e.g., $HOME/workspace/myProject).

Having the images in src/ (which is automatically copied to bin/) didn't do the trick on Eclipse Luna.

Answer (score 0):

It is very simple to adding an image into project and view the image.
First create a folder into in your project which can contain any type of images.

Then Right click on Project `->>`Go to Build Path `->>` configure Build Path `->>` add Class folder `->>` choose your folder (which you just created for store the images) under the project name.

```
class Surface extends JPanel {

    private BufferedImage slate;
    private BufferedImage java;
    private BufferedImage pane;
    private TexturePaint slatetp;
    private TexturePaint javatp;
    private TexturePaint panetp;

    public Surface() {

        loadImages();
    }

    private void loadImages() {

        try {

            slate = ImageIO.read(new File("images\\slate.png"));
            java = ImageIO.read(new File("images\\java.png"));
            pane = ImageIO.read(new File("images\\pane.png"));

        } catch (IOException ex) {

            Logger.`enter code here`getLogger(Surface.class.getName()).log(
                    Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
        }
    }

    private void doDrawing(Graphics g) {

        Graphics2D g2d = (Graphics2D) g.create();

        slatetp = new TexturePaint(slate, new Rectangle(0, 0, 90, 60));
        javatp = new TexturePaint(java, new Rectangle(0, 0, 90, 60));
        panetp = new TexturePaint(pane, new Rectangle(0, 0, 90, 60));

        g2d.setPaint(slatetp);
        g2d.fillRect(10, 15, 90, 60);

        g2d.setPaint(javatp);
        g2d.fillRect(130, 15, 90, 60);

        g2d.setPaint(panetp);
        g2d.fillRect(250, 15, 90, 60);

        g2d.dispose();
    }

    @Override
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

        super.paintComponent(g);
        doDrawing(g);
    }
}

public class TexturesEx extends JFrame {

    public TexturesEx() {

        initUI();
    }

    private void initUI() {

        add(new Surface());

        setTitle("Textures");
        setSize(360, 120);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);        
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            @Override
            public void run() {
                TexturesEx ex = new TexturesEx();
                ex.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are doing it in eclipse, there are a few quick notes that if you are hovering your mouse over a class  in your script, it will show a focus dialogue that says hit f2 for focus.

for computer apps, use ImageIcon. and for the path say,

```
ImageIcon thisImage = new ImageIcon("images/youpic.png");
```

specify the folder( images) then seperate with / and add the name of the pic file.

I hope this is helpful. If someone else posted it, I didn't read through. So...yea.. thought reinforcement.