# image source path exception in java program

Tags: java, eclipse

I am following [this](http://zetcode.com/tutorials/javaswingtutorial/puzzle/) tutorial using eclipse. I am getting an exception for an image path. I made a folder `images` in programs `src` directory & put image into it. I also tried putting image directly into `src` folder. But same rsult.

Here is program & stack trace for exception.

**Esception:**

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at javax.swing.ImageIcon.<init>(Unknown Source)
    at Puzzle.initUI(Puzzle.java:47)
    at Puzzle.<init>(Puzzle.java:31)
    at Puzzle$1.run(Puzzle.java:141)
    at java.awt.event.InvocationEvent.dispatch(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEventImpl(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.access$000(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue$1.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
    at java.security.AccessControlContext$1.doIntersectionPrivilege(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventQueue.dispatchEvent(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpOneEventForFilters(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForFilter(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEventsForHierarchy(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.pumpEvents(Unknown Source)
    at java.awt.EventDispatchThread.run(Unknown Source)
```

**Java Program:**

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.GridLayout;
import java.awt.Image;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.awt.image.CropImageFilter;
import java.awt.image.FilteredImageSource;

import javax.swing.Box;
import javax.swing.ImageIcon;
import javax.swing.JButton;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;

public class Puzzle extends JFrame implements ActionListener {

    private JPanel centerPanel;
    private JButton button;
    private JLabel label;
    private Image source;
    private Image image;
    int[][] pos;
    int width, height;

    public Puzzle() {

        initUI();
    }

    public final void initUI() {

        pos = new int[][]{
                    {0, 1, 2},
                    {3, 4, 5},
                    {6, 7, 8},
                    {9, 10, 11}
                };


        centerPanel = new JPanel();
        centerPanel.setLayout(new GridLayout(4, 4, 0, 0));

        ImageIcon sid = new ImageIcon(Puzzle.class.getResource("/images/mickey.jpg"));
        source = sid.getImage();

        width = sid.getIconWidth();
        height = sid.getIconHeight();


        add(Box.createRigidArea(new Dimension(0, 5)), BorderLayout.NORTH);
        add(centerPanel, BorderLayout.CENTER);


        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++) {
            for (int j = 0; j < 3; j++) {
                if (j == 2 && i == 3) {
                    label = new JLabel("");
                    centerPanel.add(label);
                } else {
                    button = new JButton();
                    button.addActionListener(this);
                    centerPanel.add(button);
                    image = createImage(new FilteredImageSource(source.getSource(),
                            new CropImageFilter(j * width / 3, i * height / 4,
                            (width / 3) + 1, height / 4)));
                    button.setIcon(new ImageIcon(image));
                }
            }
        }

        setSize(325, 275);
        setTitle("Puzzle");
        setResizable(false);
        setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        JButton button = (JButton) e.getSource();
        Dimension size = button.getSize();

        int labelX = label.getX();
        int labelY = label.getY();
        int buttonX = button.getX();
        int buttonY = button.getY();
        int buttonPosX = buttonX / size.width;
        int buttonPosY = buttonY / size.height;
        int buttonIndex = pos[buttonPosY][buttonPosX];



        if (labelX == buttonX && (labelY - buttonY) == size.height) {

            int labelIndex = buttonIndex + 3;

            centerPanel.remove(buttonIndex);
            centerPanel.add(label, buttonIndex);
            centerPanel.add(button, labelIndex);
            centerPanel.validate();
        }

        if (labelX == buttonX && (labelY - buttonY) == -size.height) {

            int labelIndex = buttonIndex - 3;
            centerPanel.remove(labelIndex);
            centerPanel.add(button, labelIndex);
            centerPanel.add(label, buttonIndex);
            centerPanel.validate();
        }

        if (labelY == buttonY && (labelX - buttonX) == size.width) {

            int labelIndex = buttonIndex + 1;

            centerPanel.remove(buttonIndex);
            centerPanel.add(label, buttonIndex);
            centerPanel.add(button, labelIndex);
            centerPanel.validate();
        }

        if (labelY == buttonY && (labelX - buttonX) == -size.width) {

            int labelIndex = buttonIndex - 1;

            centerPanel.remove(buttonIndex);
            centerPanel.add(label, labelIndex);
            centerPanel.add(button, labelIndex);
            centerPanel.validate();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

            public void run() {
                Puzzle puzzle = new Puzzle();
                puzzle.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }
}
```

**Directory structure:**

```
swingExamples (it's java project)
 --src
 --bin
 --images
 --.settings
```

Answer (score 2):

You need the image file on the class path for the built program, not in the source folder. That means wherever your Puzzle.class file is being compiled to, you will need an Images folder with the jpeg on the root of your class path. If you provide the directory structure for your program I can help you out more.

Comment: I put directory structure at the end of OP

Comment: In this case, you would want to put your Images folder in the bin folder I believe.

Comment: OK, thank you for the help. This post help me solve the problem:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5657469/how-do-i-go-about-adding-an-image-into-a-java-project-with-eclipse

Answer (score 0):

To load your image(s) you can create a new package within your src project or the project which you are working on and name it images, then drag and drop your image(s) directly onto the images project explorer in your IDE. After you do this you can see the image(s) included in the project explorer, below your images project.
Then now you need to go to your getResource method and in the arguments type (for example):

..........getResource(""/images/lion.png"));

This works for me.