# How to change getResource to getResourceAsStream

Tags: java, file

The program runs well with getResource, but after made it into the jar file, it has `FileNotFoundException`. It cannot find out test.conf.

My code is

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("test.conf");
File fin = new File(url.getPath());

FileInputStream fis = null;
try {
    fis = new FileInputStream(fin);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

I think I can fix the problem by using getResourceAsStream. But I'm not sure how to change getResource to getResourceAsStream.

Comment: Stop considering that resources are files. They are not. Instead of reading the FIle by opening a FileInputStream, read directly from the InputStream returned by getResourceAsStream(). If you showed us the code using that file, we could help more.

Comment: test.conf has to be located in the root folder

Comment: I've added more details.

Comment: @sidgate root folder?? which root

Comment: OK. So you open a FileInputStream to read bytes from the resource. Just don't do that, and read directly from the InputStream returned by getResourceAsStream(). Reading from that InputStream is no different from reading from a FileInputStream. They are both InputStreams.

Comment: Why FileInputStream is not ok in this case?

Answer (score 0):

Your example suggests that your reading code already works on a FileInputStream. You should be able to make it work with the more general InputStream. This will allow you to just pass the result of getResourceStream() to your reading code, without having to worry about Files.

So:

```
URL url = getClass().getResource("test.conf");
File fin = new File(url.getPath());

FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(fin);

ReadResourceFromStream(fis);
```

Changes to:

```
InputStream is = getClass().getResourceAsStream("test.conf");

ReadResourceFromStream(is);
```

Comment: Did you make any progress with it?